# how to remove underscore from filename in directory using modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, batch

Does anyone have a script I can use in modelbuilder that will?:

- parse an "_" from a filename
- usable in modelbuilder with an inline variable (%name%) and Feature class iterator
- transfer or copy the actual renamed shapefiles to another folder?

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can use a bit of Python and simply call `string.replace('_', '')` to remove the underscore.

Comment: I downvoted because this was asking someone else to do research for them.

Comment: I would say the question is well within the bounds of the rules and format of GIS SE.

Comment: @Pete this is the kind of thing which is hard to find if you don't know what words to use when searching, and eyes-closed easy when you do know the words.

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/add-arbitrary-code-to-arcgis-model-builder

Comment: They don't teach you these things in high school, but... don't put the underscore in there to begin with.

Comment: fair enough downvote rescinded.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing a Python script tool you should be able to use a **[Calculate Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v8000000)** tool with the Python code recommended by @blah238:

```
r"%name%".replace("_","")
```

The next step will be to use the **[Rename](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000056000000)** tool to use the text string this creates to rename the feature class.

Comment: A slight clarification. There is a distinction between the [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) of [built-in sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) like `str` and `unicode`, and methods of the actual [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string) module. Use of the built-in methods is preferred. So in the Calculate Value tool's expression box, you would enter something like `r"%name%".replace("_","")`.

Comment: The calculate value with the expression r"%name%".replace("_","") still doesn't work. This operation seems simple enough but still no luck. Do I need to define the workspace or parse a path?

Comment: Actually, I take that back; the Calculate Value tool works with the expression r"%name%".replace("_","") but how do you transfer or copy the actual renamed shapefiles to another folder? I can see the renamed shapefiles with the Collect Values. Almost there!

Comment: I would suggest using [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000) instead, as the OP would like to copy the shapefiles over to a new folder.

Answer (score 2):

Building on PolyGeo's answer above, the `Collect Values` tool is not necessary, because as you iterate over the shapefiles, each one should be renamed and copied once only.

[image]

In the image above, the shapefiles are renamed and copied one at a time as the iterator iterates over them. Make sure to check the `recursive` checkbox in the iterator dialog if your folder contains subfolders.

Comment: Renaming as part of the copy makes sense (+1) but I think when you said "the Collect Values tool is not necessary" you meant "the Rename tool is not necessary".

Comment: I duplicated the model above but I'm still getting the  the "_" underscore in the filename for my output files. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PolyGeo I meant that if the recursive checkbox is ticked, the `Collect Values` is not necessary because it will iterate over each shapefile anyway, therefore `Copy Features` will run for each iteration and copy each shp.

Comment: @galindo If you used PolyGeo's string replacement in the Calculate Value tool, then your `parsed_filename` contains the new shp name without underscores.

Comment: I see what you mean - I had been talking about Calulate Value and had not noticed that @Galinda had a Collect Values tool in his/her model.

Comment: What's the simplest way to extract the renamed shapefiles (from a Collect Values tool) to another folder? Copy features won't do it.